# The form template has been published to the server but it can only be opened in infopath filler

Tags: sharepoint-server, infopath, 2016, windows-server-2016

I am using SharePoint 2016 on Windows Server 2016 (with GUI). Created a new SharePoint 2010 type workflow and started approval process which automatically created a task form. I then opened that task form in InfoPath 2013 and tried to publish it without making any changes but getting error:

```
The form template has been published to the server but it can only be opened in infopath filler
```

I keep seeing that I need to enable Desktop Experience but that is for Windows 2012. I am not sure if I have Desktop Experience on Windows Server 2016 but I am connected via RDP and there is GUI and everything so I guess Desktop Experience is enabled?

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You may check your version of Windows Server 2016 via registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\InstallationType
```

For OS with Desktop Experience, the `REG_SZ` Value is "**Server**" and otherwise the value is "**Server Core**".

You cannot just enable this feature if you are in another version, a clean installation is required.

Reference: [programmatically check if desktop experience is installed or not windows server 2016.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39116164/programmatically-check-if-desktop-experience-is-installed-or-not-windows-server)

Comment: Installation type is "Server"